# Why AnyObject or Any conversion is failing to GADUnifiedNativeAd in swift5?

Tags: swift, swift5, anyobject

I am using Google Ad and I am converting `GADUnifiedNativeAd` to `AnyObject` and converting back original `GADUnifiedNativeAd` is failing in Swift 5 . What can be the reason? Before this code working fine in Swift 4.2 and below:

[GADUnifiedNativeAd](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/api/reference/Classes/GADUnifiedNativeAd)

on delegate response of fetching Ad

```swift
func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
    let anyObjectTo: AnyObject = nativeAd
    if let nativeAd = anyObjectTo as? GADUnifiedNativeAd {
        print("success")
    } else {
        print("failing")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting to/from `AnyObject`? Can you provide more context?

Comment: `nativeAd` is `GADUnifiedNativeAd` by default, why do you have to convert it to `AnyObject` and then converting it back?

Comment: is that `as?` supposed to be `is`?

Comment: in my project we holding in array of AnyObject for all type of ads and converting as per the type we are converting  like GADUnifiedNativeAd or GADNativeCustomTemplateAd some things like this

Comment: @Sulthan I want to convert is back to if let adObject = adInfo as? GADUnifiedNativeAd {
                customNativeAd = adObject
            }  which is failing

Comment: one things it solve like use GADUnifiedNativeAd but I want to know the reason failing

Comment: The code makes no sense at all. The `nativeAd` parameter is a non-optional `GADUnifiedNativeAd` object. This is Swift. It can't be something else.

Comment: @vadian the issue I am suspecting is  GADUnifiedNativeAd is objc class . isa pointer is changing to GADUnifiedNativeAd -> GADNUnifiedNativeAd of type  on assign to AnyObject which is different type. which I can see debugger.               Printing description of anyObjectTo:
<GADNUnifiedNativeAd: 0x282b26bc0>

Comment: i think you're missing `let` in `if anyObjectTo as? GADUnifiedNativeAd`

Comment: I am experiencing the same